# Xpath using sibblings or fellowing in two defrent Cell

Tags: html, xpath

Put bluntly I want to locate TestCoupon10% inside td then open a sibling td then locate //a[contains(@id,"cmdOpen")] I did try sibling and fellowing but likely I didnt do it right because

//span[./text()="TestCoupon10%"]/following-sibling:a[contains(@id,"cmdOpen")]
result into an invalid xpath. the HTML structure look as fellow

```
<tr>
 <td>
  <span id="oCouponGrid_ctl03_lblCode">TestCoupon10%</span>
 </td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td>...</td>
 <td valign="middle" align=""right">
  <a id="oCouponGrid_ctl03_cmdOpen">
 </td>
</tr>
```

I need to find cmdOpen and test coupon does anyone has an idea how to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axes are delimited with double colons, not single ones (those are used for namespace prefixes). You wanted to say this:

```
//span[./text()="TestCoupon10%"]/following-sibling::a[contains(@id,"cmdOpen")]
```

**But** - the `<a>` is not a following sibling of the `<span>` in question. You need to do some navigating:

```
//span[./text()="TestCoupon10%"]/parent::td/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@id,"cmdOpen")]
```

Or, simply avoid descending into the tree you you don't have to "climb up" again in the first place.

```
//td[span = "TestCoupon10%"]/following-sibling::td/a[contains(@id,"cmdOpen")]
```